# PhpStorm doesn't recognise exceptions via PHPDoc inside closures

Tags: exception, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have some method and a closure inside it. Exception can be thrown in this closure. This exception is declared in methods PHPDoc, but PhpStorm says that this exception is never thrown.

Do anyone know how to make PhpStorm see it? Declaring another PHPDoc before closure does not help.

Code looks like this:

```
/**
 * @throws IAmInvisibleException - Sorry, but I don't know you
 */
private function some_nice_method(){
    $some_var = (function(){
        if($something_wrong)
            throw new IAmInvisibleException();
    })();
}
```

Comment: What is your IDE version? Seems to work for me in a test project (2018.2.5)

Comment: Happens in 2018.3. Probably the same as [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39500) (says it's been this way since 2017.3.6, weird that it doesn't happen for you @LazyOne).

Comment: @LazyOne version 2018.3

Comment: @Jeto you are right, it's the same issue and seems like happening only with custom exceptions

Comment: Well ... I've initially tested with standard `UnexpectedValueException` and it works fine. But with custom one -- yes, I do see the same. So yeah -- follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39500